# How to return output in node using Async Detect Series

Tags: javascript, node.js, series, async.js

Actually i wanted to return some output based on some asynchronous calls while iterating an array and executing a method over it. When i get a desired response from let's say a Third Party Server, I want to stop the Iteration and return the response as received from server.

So for this purpose i have used async package in node. I am using [Detect Series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#detectSeries) for this purpose.

This is my call, i am iterating over an array of elements. Lets say i am calling a method over array of numbers.

```
async.detectSeries([1, 5, 7, 9, 6, 13, 14], checkIfEven, function(err, res) {
        callback(null, res); 
         // res should be coming
         // "Yes I found the Number 6"
         // But coming only 6
    });
```

So Basically all i need is response whenever first even number is found and after that iteration should stop. No further execution.

Below is a generic method to check if number is even or not.

```
checkIfEven(number, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            //Truthy Condition
            callback(null, "Yes I found the Number"+number);
        } else {
           //Falsy Condition
            callback(null, false);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Based on that return the string

> "Yes I found the Number"+number-found

Something like that, a response over which i have control. But all i am getting is number itself in the success callback. In this case it will be 6.

So it is just returning the number in the array which passes the test first. It server half the purpose in identifying the number, but lets say i want the response which i will be getting after applying a method over the parameter.

Please let me know where i am going wrong. Or any other better approach to solve this issue, Thanks

Comment: use `callback("found number"+number)` instead of `callback(null,"found number")` , when error is null the loop will iterate to the next element. If loop encounter error then the last callback is called.

Comment: `when error is null the loop will iterate to the next element` this is not true for `detectSeries`. Async's documentation state the final callback **is called as soon as any iteratee returns true, or after all the iteratee functions have finished**.

Answer (score 0):

When using `detectSeries`, the *iteratee*'s callback expects a boolean value, and the final result will contain the array item that passes the test, not the value with which you called the callback. Any string you pass to it will simply be interpeted as `true`.

On `checkIfEven`, return only `true` or `false`.

Call your `callback` on the final callback with `res` contents.

```
function checkIfEven(number, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            //Truthy Condition
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
           //Falsy Condition
            callback(null, false);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

async.detectSeries([1, 5, 7, 9, 6, 13, 14], checkIfEven, function(err, res) {
    callback(null, "Yes I found the Number " + res);
});
```